# Angularjs listen on attribute's callback function in custom directive

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-directive, angular-ui-typeahead

Angular-ui bootstrap provides typeahead functionality and one of the directives is `typeahead-on-select` which takes a callback function as an argument, e.g. `typeahead-on-select="onSelectItem($item, $model, $label)"`. Is it somehow possible to intercept or listen for this `typeahead-on-select` in my own custom directive **(not controller)**?

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/mutesvhp/

I want to add bunch of custom validation when user selects something from dropdown and I don't want to pollute my controller with many instances of this code : `$scope.myCustomForm.myCustomInput.$setValidity("somethingCustom", false);` based on different scenarios. I'd rather have it in validation directive.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the demo: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mutesvhp/1/). Select `first` will make the validation not passed.

I tend to like using isolate scope for two-way binding like:

```
myApp.directive('myDir', function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            ngModel: '=',
            hasError: '='
        },
        controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {
            $scope.$watch('ngModel', function (model) {
                console.log('Selected: ' + model);
                if (model === 'first') {
                    $scope.hasError = true;
                }
            });
        }]
    }
});
```

And the HTML:

```
<input data-ng-model="myModel" 
       typeahead="item for item in items"
       typeahead-on-select="onSelectItem($item, $model, $label)"
       ng-class="{error: hasError}"
       data-has-error="hasError"
       my-dir>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the only problem with your approach is that you are listening on model change which happens on every key press. I was looking more for watching when users selects an item from "dropdown", only then do some validation. (Or when user types a matching result and hits enter, which is something I'll look how to implement once I figure out onSelect one)